# threading using extend Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I can get my method threadR to run by a runnable thread, however i cant seem to get threadL to run as a thread and print out to the console

`System.out.println("Greetings from Fred! threadL");` from my run thread

What am i doing wrong?

```
package threads;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Threads extends Thread implements Runnable  {

private final List<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
private String e,l;
private Thread greetings;


public static void main(String[] args) {

String[] elements = {"Tim","Fred"};    
Threads t = new Threads();
for (String e: elements) {  
t.threadL(e);
t.threadR(e);
}



for(int index = 0;index<t.threadList.size();index++){
System.out.print(t.threadList.get(index).getName()+ " ID "+          t.threadList.get(index).getId()+"\n");

}
}



public List<Thread> threadL(String l)  {
Thread greetings1 = new Thread(l);

greetings1.start();
threadList.add(greetings1);
//System.out.print(greetings.getName()+"\n");
//System.out.print(greetings.getId()+"\n");
   return(threadList);

}
public List<Thread> threadR(String f)    {
greetings = new Thread(f);
Thread greetingsFromFred = new Thread(greetings) { 
 @Override
 public void run() { 
     System.out.println("Greetings from Fred! threadR");

}
}; greetingsFromFred.start();

threadList.add(greetings);
//System.out.print(greetings.getName()+"\n");
//System.out.print(greetings.getId()+"\n");
   return(threadList);
 }

    public void run() {
         System.out.println("Greetings from Fred! threadL");  //this is what wont run 
    }
```

Comment: reviewing code is easier when it is formatted

Comment: You're creating too many thread... explain what you're trying to achieve, there is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: @ CtrlAltDel I have only created 2 extra threads one called Tim and Fred which runs under the method threadR. I am then trying to do the same under method threadL, so a further 2 threads. Aside from the main thread. I am just doing some experimentation to understand threads better for implementation on a table model.

Comment: @ CtrlAltDel I am trying to get greetings1.start() to start and therefore print out System.out.println("Greetings from Fred! threadL");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a String as the only argument to `new Thread(String);` you are actually setting the Thread name. You probably meant to pass a Runnable to the Thread as such

```
Thread greetings1 = new Thread(this);
```

[Thread Constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.String))

Comment: yes this is doing exactly as  i want - i didnt spot that and couldnt think where it was going wrong